# Hyperlink in a Datalist

Tags: asp.net

How do I create a hyperlink on a DataList in .NET?

Answer (score 6):

```
<asp:DataList id="DataList1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink Runat =server NavigateUrl ='<%#"webform1.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productid").ToString()%>' ID="Hyperlink1">
          <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName")%>
     </asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```