# How to make website URL from Datalist in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

How can I make a website linkable URL from `Datalist` in asp.net with c#?

I have tried `Hyperlink` but no one action event thr.

I can Navigate to a specific url, when I click on it, it goes to c# to respond to a new URL.

Comment: you can use navigateurl with HyperLink.

Comment: @Chirag-i have tried but datalist itself hyperlink but its not redirecting new Tab.i mean no one action thr... thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Davide Piras has mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401565/make-datalist-items-link-able-in-asp-net)

you should edit the item template of the DataList and put an ASP HyperLink inside, and you use data binding to assign the NavigateUrl to such control.

something like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="listSearchResults" Border="1" BorderColor="Black"
    RepeatDirect="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>

     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

another approach is to use ASP:LinkButton and assign CommandName and CommandArgument properties to that control.

Comment: -suppose we are given link button means how we can set as from code behind in command argument how? Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
<asp:DataList id="DataList1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("YourUrl") %>' Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' runat="server"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Example of hyperlink in ItemTemplate field :- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22087934/2798643) and [Here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2361165/2798643)

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar-Thank u very much its working sooooper